# Starting a New Vibration Pattern Restting The Old Pattern

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

I have created this simple application where the user clicks a button that results in a vibration pattern being executed.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

Though, when the user presses that button it starts the pattern again which results in overlapping vibration patterns. I want the user to be able to press the button which will result in the pattern starting over without being mixed with the old pattern.

I have tried using v.cancel() before v.vibrate(). That did not help at all. I guess from my basic understanding v.cancel() starts async and this means the cancel does not happen right away. I have thought of modifying the settings but I have found out that, it will not help (I think). I have even thought of adding the vibration code in a separate thread or something then killing the thread altogether (will that help). I have to learn how to handle threads. I am trying to do this quickly due to project deadlines. If the thread idea is working for someone, please let me know so I learn threads.

I am just confused on why the SDK makes it hard to reset the vibration or stop it completely.

Comment: on button clicked set yourBtn.setEnabled(false); and when your pattern finish .setEnabled(true);

Comment: @MilosLulic there's no callback to know when the vibration is finished, so that isn't really possible.

Comment: but you know duration in ms of pattern?

Comment: The issue I am having is I want the user to be able to click the button either way. So, I want to come up with a way for the user to reset the already vibrating pattern. My pattern is long and has plenty of pauses. Yes, I do know the length. Thanks.

Comment: I have explored the thread and permission options and failed. Is interrupting the vibration pattern an impossibility?